# How to thicken/enlarge certain areas of a model?

Tags: modeling, bones

How can I enlargen the fins and ribcage of the fish below? 
I need to 3D print the model but currently at the moment the peices are too small to print or they snap off after being printed!!!I just need to make them thicker so that this wont happen.

[image: Photo of fish. I need to enlargen the fins and ribcage]

Comment: have you tried to fatten with alt S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use **Displace modifier** with vertex group to enlarge the delicate part.

[image]

Comment: I swear I didn't mean to create this shape.....